# How remove emacs full?

Tags: emacs, uninstallation, apt-get

I installed Emacs in my Ubuntu and I cannot uninstall (and cannot install anything more)

```
▶ sudo apt-get install tig
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs-bin-common : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 emacs-el : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
 emacs-gtk : Depends: emacs-common (= 1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to run the command `apt --fix-broken install`, and I receive this error message:

```
▶ sudo apt --fix-broken install -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  emacs-common
Suggested packages:
  emacs-common-non-dfsg ncurses-term
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  emacs-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 68,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 185527 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../emacs-common_1%3a26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs-common (1:26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el', which is also in package emacs26-common 26.2~1.gitfd1b34b-kk1+19.04
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-common_1%3a26.1+1-3.2ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: This post saved my life........ https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: The message "which is also in package emacs26-common" suggests to me that you have (parts of) both the "emacs*" and "emacs26*" sets of packages installed.  Presumably the latter would be from some non-default PPA.  What does `dpkg --get-selections | grep emacs` tell you?

Answer (score 17):

Try to remove the broken packages which have missing dependencies e.g.

```
sudo apt remove --purge emacs-bin-common emacs-el emacs-gtk
```

If that doesn't work, try again with the --force flag added.

How did you try to uninstall emacs initially?

Answer (score 2):

**Using apt**

```
sudo apt remove emacs
```

followed by

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

this will remove both emacs-terminal and emacs-GUI

Answer (score 1):

First, remove from Ubuntu software. If not removed, then try to use this command for broken package:

`sudo apt remove --purge emacs-bin-common emacs-el emacs-gtk`